# how to include multiple code coverage's in the pipeline

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, azure-devops, code-coverage

I have an entity framework .net core application as a backend and .net core react app for the front-end.

I am trying to setup *azure pipelines* for this project.

While I am setting the pipeline for **.net core react** app I am running the library tests (code coverage is generated) also as it is the referenced project to my UI project.

The Issue here is when I run the **JEST** tests for the .net core react app, it is also generating test coverage but in the summary of build pipeline test coverage tab is not showing the code coverage when I enable the code coverage of library.

I am able to see both coverages in the artifacts published.

**How can I see both coverages in my build summary?**

Comment: JEST code coverage is not supported by Azure Pipelines Build yet.

Comment: Sorry @EriawanKusumawardhono Jest code coverage works in azure build. Not displaying in the Test coverage Tab when I have another code coverage by VSTEST  but it is in the artifacts but links to navigate to the files wont work. :(

Comment: I have the same problem. Having a 'PublishTestResults@2" task for my .net core tests and "PublishCodeCoverageResults@1" for Cobertura is only displaying the .NET Core results in the "Code coverage" taband the Cobertura results are only visible in the build artifacts.

Answer (score 3):

To combine multiple coverage reports into one, you can use the `reportgenerator` task. The `reportgenerator` takes multiple coverage files and combines them into one single coverage file. This new coverage file can then be published using the

Example:

```
steps:
- task: Palmmedia.reportgenerator.reportgenerator-build-release-task.reportgenerator@4
  displayName: ReportGenerator
  inputs:
    reports: '*\TestResults\*\coverage.cobertura.xml'
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: 'coveragereport\Cobertura.xml'
    failIfCoverageEmpty: true
```

Here's an article that describes this in greater detail: https://www.jamescroft.co.uk/combining-multiple-code-coverage-results-in-azure-devops/

Answer (score 1):

> how to include multiple code coverage's in the pipeline

It seems you are using the [Publish Code Coverage Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=vsts) task, it's unlike to use Publish test results task. But you could not be able to publish multiple coverage test results in a single task.

When you have two `coverage.xml` files, Azure Devops Build definition will only use one of them.

To resolve this issue, try to add another Publish Code Coverage Results task in build pipeline for each package.

If it not helps you, please share your build definition in your question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

In my pipeline I already have a build step to publish test(jest) coverage, and VS Test by default creating a test coverage (checkbox selected) and  published in to the artifacts. If I stop the code coverage of VS Test the jest coverage is working fine.

Comment: I don't think you can publish more than one set of code coverage results, per [this Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops#q--a) on the Publish Code Coverage Results task documentation.
Specifically, "If you use multiple publish code coverage tasks in the pipeline, the summary and report is shown for the last task. Any previously uploaded data is ignored."

Answer (score 0):

Using the [PublishCodeCoverageResults@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-code-coverage-results-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task, you can publish multiple code coverage reports. According to its documentation, **multiple summary files are merged into a single report**.

For instance, consider this project setup:

```
|- backend
   |- requirements.txt
   |- ...
|- frontend
   |- package.json
   |- ...
|- azure-pipelines.yaml
|- docker-compose.yaml
|- README.md
```

The `backend` folder contains a FastAPI application that serves API to the frontend service. The `frontend` folder contains a Vue.js application (*generated by Vite*) that visualizes the data, retrieved from the backend service.

The content of the `azure-pipelines.yaml` file is the following:

```
stages:
- stage: Test
  displayName: Test and Lint Stage
  jobs:
  - job: Backend
    displayName: Test and Lint Backend Service
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.10'
    - script: python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
      displayName: Upgrade pip and setuptools
    - script: python -m pip install -r $(backendDirName)/requirements.txt -r $(backendDirName)/requirements-dev.txt
      displayName: Install all dependencies
    - script: pre-commit run --all-files
      workingDirectory: $(backendDirName)
      displayName: Check code quality
    - script: |
        coverage run -m pytest
        coverage xml -o coverage.xml
      workingDirectory: $(backendDirName)
      displayName: Generate coverage report
    - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
      inputs:
        summaryFileLocation: '**/coverage.xml'
  - job: Frontend
    displayName: Test and Lint Frontend Service
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.x'
        checkLatest: true
    - script: npm install
      workingDirectory: $(frontendDirName)
      displayName: Install all dependencies
    - script: npm run lint
      workingDirectory: $(frontendDirName)
      displayName: Check code quality
    - script: npm run coverage
      workingDirectory: $(frontendDirName)
      displayName: Generate coverage report
    - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
      inputs:
        summaryFileLocation: '**/clover.xml'
```

There are five major steps for the backend and the frontend service.

- **Configuring the environment**: Python 3.10 version is used for the backend. Node 18 version is used for the frontend service.
- **Installing dependencies**: Dependencies are installed by using `pip` and `npm` tools. Make sure that you include `coverage` + `pytest` and the `@vitest/coverage-v8` packages (or similar) in your dependencies.
- **Linting source code** (optional): Checking code quality using `pre-commit` and `eslint` tools. Install them before execution.
- **Generating code coverage**: The [Coverage.py](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy) for the backend and the [Vitest](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest) for the fronted were used to create the coverage report.
- **Publishing coverage report**: At the end, the reports were published by `PublishCodeCoverageResults@2` tasks. It collects the `coverage.xml` report for the backend and the `clover.xml` for the frontend.

Note that, the `workingDirectory` parameter ensures to start of the scripts in different directories.

When the pipeline is finished, it merges the two reports together. Navigate to the **Code Coverage**  tab under the **Pipelines** page.

[image]

As you can see, the code coverage reports are present. It also calculates the average code coverage across the services.